# Saving a apt-get file for future installations, how do I do it?

Tags: apt

I have a terribly limited download allowance and have multiple computers. So, my questions folks is. Would I be able to save what has been installed thru apt-get and any other terminal installations I attempt?

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/123411/save-deb-files-from-var-cache-apt-archives-folder-for-future-installation?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a server/spare box, you can [setup Apt-Cacher](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Apt-Cacher-Server), which will store all of the .deb files for you.

Answer (score 6):

When you install a package using `apt-get` corresponding `deb` files are downloaded in your `/var/cache/apt/archives`. Unless user deletes them all those files should be there. You can copy and preserve them for future use.

All you need is to set a local repository<sup>[[Source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1090731)]</sup>. Then you could install all those packages as usual using `apt-get` from it. Make a folder `localrepo` say at you home directory and put all the `.deb` files from `/var/cache/apt/archives` in it.

```
$ mkdir ~/localrepo
$ cp /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb .
```

Next you need to create an index file for your repository. For that you need to install `dpkg-dev` (on your source machine only).

```
$ sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev
```

To create index file,

```
$ cd ~/localrepo
$ dpkg-scanpackages . /dev/null | gzip -9c > Packages.gz
```

It will create an index file named `Packages.gz` in `~/localrepo`. In future you just need to copy the whole `~/localrepo` to other machines where you want to install. If you modify the deb files in `~/localrepo` you also need to update the index file.

Now you need to show `apt-get` the repo editing your source list in all machines where you want to install packages from your local repository. First backup your original `source.list`

```
$ sudo cp /etc/apt/source.list /etc/apt/source.list.original
$ sudo gedit /etc/apt/source.list
```

Write the following line in it and save,

```
deb file:/home/<user_name>/localrepo ./
```

Replace `<user_name>` with your exact user name. Now you are ready to install any package that exists in your source machine.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install <package_name>
```

You may need to give additional affirmation. As the repository is not trusted. For home use purpose it should be just enough as [creation of a trusted repo](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1090731) requires quite a lot extra efforts. But your software center will not probably work with untrusted repo. But the advantage is that it will take care of all the dependencies for a package by itself.

If your `/var/cache/apt/archives` in your source machine do not contain any package. You can download deb files for all your existing packages using the following command in terminal,<sup>[[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86358/how-to-obtain-installed-package-files)]</sup>

```
dpkg -l | grep "^ii"| awk ' {print $2} ' | xargs sudo apt-get -y install --reinstall --download-only
```

Comment: That is a beautiful response my man. After looking thru the directory /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb, I wanted to ask, is there a way of seperating updates from this as well?

Comment: @Miphix I could not see an easy way right now. It may be another good question.

Comment: Just remember me if you brew up something. Ooh, is there a way of cataloging and indexing these installations?