# Setting up a local repository: need help

Tags: installation, apt, repository

I am attempting to set up a local Ubuntu repository following [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Offline/Repository/), but I need some help. To test if I did everything correctly, I tried `sudo apt-get install chrome` or `sudo apt-get install nodejs` but I get *Unable to locate package x.* Since I followed the official documentation linked above precisely, I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

1. Why do people suggest using `apt-mirror` or `apt-catcher`? Are they necessary?
2. Do I have to unzip `Packages.bz2` or `Packages.gz`? Is it right that I just leave them as they are?
3. Am I missing an important step?

I haven't figured out a solution after doing some research. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Related, may help you. http://askubuntu.com/a/408845/127327

Answer (score 1):

First question, you don't have to use `apt-mirror` its just for getting `.deb` files into your local repo. You can get the `.deb` by other means:

1. you can install the application you need on online system with internet connection then you can cop the `.deb` files from `/var/cache/apt/archives` to your local repo.
2. If you don't want to install you can just download the `.deb` of needed package by `sudo apt-get dowload package-name` then you can find the `.deb` in your home so you can move to your local repo.

Second question, you don't have to unzip the Packages.gz. Its a file containing archive of packages founded in your local repo. you have just to keep it there and don't mess with.

Third question, just move on with the link you provide and you ara fine. If you don't get the needed just check this [How to create a local APT repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170348/how-to-make-my-own-local-repository). you can find many methods to make a local repo either with web server(apache2) or just a local directory.