# how to transfer and install a software from one system to another?

Tags: 12.10, apt, transfer

I have already installed VLC in my Ubuntu 12.10 and i wish to transfer it to my friend who has no internet connection.so please help me out.

Comment: see this post [Saving a apt-get file for future installations](http://askubuntu.com/a/408845/127327), may be of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [aptoncd](https://packages.debian.org/sid/aptoncd)

APT removable repository creator and package backup tool for Debian based systems.

This tool will allow you to create a media (CD or DVD) to use to install software via APT in a non-connected machine, as well upgrade and install the same set of softwares in several machines with no need to re-download the packages again.

Run the following to install the package via  terminal
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install aptoncd
```

It makes a copy of all the packages on your system allowing you to install those packages on another system.

Just a side note, you could also copy all the deb files for the packages you have installed (as long as you haven't run `sudo apt-get clean` to clean the apt-get cache) from

```
/var/cache/apt/archives
```

Comment: thank u for your reply......it does work....but when i checked my installed packages using aptoncd i cant find vlc but i have vlc installed.

Comment: Try 2nd method.check /var/cache/apt/archives folder wheater you have .deb package for vlc. If you have you can simply copy to your friends computer and install there

Comment: thank u ...but i cleared my cache thats the problem